# Sim Card extender Circuit

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, ethernet, sim

I am looking for suggestions to solve a Sim card problem. In my system I have a microcotroller interfaced to an Lte mode and this resides in an outdoor elevated position. I would like to put the Sim card for the modem in a location which is a couple of metres away. The link to that second piece of electronics contains Ethernet lines and potentially 1-2 extra physical cables.

Are there any existing solutions to allow me to have the Sim itself in the second indoor piece of electronics. Is there such a thing as a Sim bus range extender IC? It should translate the Sim card signals to some format which can be transferred over longer distances. On the other end of the link it should do the opposite.

Any ideas guys?

Lte<-->Sim ic<----->Sim ic<--> actual physical Sim

Answer (score 2):

You will be very unlikely to find a generic solution for remoting a SIM card. The reason is that whatever device is hosting the SIM card is going to have its own set of specifications and operational characteristics that are system specific. Key things would be the access clocking rate, acceptable access delay from card and signal line integrity requirements.

It might be possible to do what you want but it would be a custom solution that is tailored to your specific device. You would need to thoroughly understand the host system access clocking rate, acceptable access delay from card and signal line integrity requirements before even attempting to design and build something that would work reliably.

Maybe you have an X-Y problem here. Why does the host device need to be mounted in an elevated position that is inconvenient. Sounds like you really should be remoting the device antenna on the end of a coax feeder cable and keep the actual hosting device at your convenient location.